# Loading xlsx file into R with unknowns, NAs, 0s, and empty space

Tags: r, load, xlsx, na

I am trying to load a xlsx file into R that has unknown values, NAs, 0s, and empty space. The unknown values are coded are coded as (-99), NAs are coded as (-88) or are EMPTY spaces, and 0s are numeric values (depending on the variable the value is either a number or a logical value) that I will recode once I load the file.

In addition to base R I am using the following packages:

- xlsx
- gdata

ID [int] | Target [int] | Preparation [int] | Criminal Charges [logical]

--- | ---| ---| ---

1 | 5 | -99 | 1

--- | --- | --- | ---

2 | -88 | --- | -88

---|---|---|---

3 | 3 | 4 | 1

---|---|---|---

4 | 3 | 3 | 0

I tried to load the file using:

```
file_1 <- read.table("file_1.xlsx", header = TRUE, fill = TRUE, row.names = NULL, na.strings = "-88", "EMPTY",
                isUnknown(x = xNum, unknown = "-99", check.names = FALSE))
```

Apart from not knowing what to have x set to in isUnknown(), I also receive error messages reading:

> line 4 appears to contain embedded nulls

I would save the file as a .csv file but the data set is very large and I received a warning message that I would lose some values if I saved it as such.

Any suggestions or directions to other references would be much appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: Don't hesitate to save as csv

Comment: If you are using the xlsx package try reading the file with 'read.xlsx(...)'

Comment: Thanks so much Dave2e. It seems that my file was able to load. I had to add sheetName = " " and I removed is.Unknown() from the code.